# One duplicate of the other

Tags: support, bug, duplicate-answers

I was checking the close queue and found this one with 4 closure votes: [How can I crop a bitmap for ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232034/java-android-how-can-i-crop-a-bitmap). All closure votes were for duplicate of [Java Android - cropping Image in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225645/java-android-cropping-image-in-imageview).

I voted to close but an error came with the following message:

> this closure would result in the 'duplicate of' navigation only
>   leading in a circle

So I flagged it for Moderator attention (it is still "active").

Now I have come back to the question and I see that it has been closed (another user could vote to close) and so two questions are closed as duplicate, each one pointing to the other.

Isn't it a bit strange? First, me not being able to vote but then another user being; then, having this circular duplication references.

PS: I tag it as "bug" although I don't know if it is. Please feel free to delete any tag that is not appropiate.

Comment: given the closures happened two hours from each other, race conditions cannot be the cause here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user there kind of shot themselves in the foot by double-posting. It's not really surprising that such deliberate miss-action on their part caused some confusion on the part of the community. I have flagged both copies, one for [re-opening](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18232034/313192) and one for [deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18225645/313192). They could also be merged if a moderator steps in to clean up the mess.

It actually makes some sense to allow voting to close in cross-wired ways since people may have different ideas about what is the better target vs duplicate, but it would be nice is such loops would cause the second close to fail or at least auto-flag for a moderator to step in and figure out what's going on.

Comment: Just saw that Bill the Lizard reopened the "bitmap" one http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18232034/revisions and the other is still closed. Thanks for answering. Also it is strange that I could not vote to close and another user could.